# Please help. Error message “sendSMS not declared in this scope” im frustrated. :(

Tags: arduino-uno

```
//INCLUDED LIBRARIES
 #include <GPRS_Shield_Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>

//SERIAL PIN ASSIGNMENT, BAUDRATE, PHONE NUMBER, MESSAGE
#define PIN_TX    2
#define PIN_RX    3
#define BAUDRATE  9600
#define PHONE_NUMBER "+639158848570"       //CELLPHONE NUMBER
#define MESSAGE  "Notice: Please be informed that your area is under Level 1 advisory with 4-inches flood depth. Continuous flood is expected due to the heavy rainfall. Be prepared and secure your important documents and belongings in high places. Avoid wirings from getting wet to prevent further injuries and accidents."  //COMPOSE YOUR MESSAGE HERE
#define MESSAGE_LENGTH <=500
char MESSAGE1;

//SERIAL PIN ASSIGNMENT, BAUDRATE, PHONE NUMBER, MESSAGE
#define PIN_TX    2
#define PIN_RX    3
#define BAUDRATE  9600
#define PHONE_NUMBER "+639379488989"       //CELLPHONE NUMBER
#define MESSAGE  "Notice: Please be informed that your area is under Level 1 advisory with 4-inches flood depth. Continuous flood is expected due to the heavy rainfall. Be prepared and secure your important documents and belongings in high places. Avoid wirings from getting wet to prevent further injuries and accidents."  //COMPOSE YOUR MESSAGE HERE
#define MESSAGE_LENGTH <=500
char MESSAGE2;


//SERIAL PIN ASSIGNMENT, BAUDRATE, PHONE NUMBER, MESSAGE
#define PIN_TX    2
#define PIN_RX    3
#define BAUDRATE  9600
#define PHONE_NUMBER "+639357120147"       //CELLPHONE NUMBER
#define MESSAGE  "Notice: Please be informed that your area is under Level 1 advisory with 4-inches flood depth. Continuous flood is expected due to the heavy rainfall. Be prepared and secure your important documents and belongings in high places. Avoid wirings from getting wet to prevent further injuries and accidents."  //COMPOSE YOUR MESSAGE HERE
#define MESSAGE_LENGTH <=500
char MESSAGE3;


char phone[16];
char datetime[24];

GPRS GSMTEST(PIN_TX,PIN_RX,BAUDRATE);//RX,TX,BAUDRATE


void loop() {
      // read the output on digital pins:
  int Level1 = digitalRead(5);
  int Level2 = digitalRead(6);
  int Level3 = digitalRead(7);

  // print out the value you read:s
  if (Level1 != 0){
    Serial.print("Level 1 =  "); Serial.print(Level1); Serial.print("   ");
    sendSMS();
  }
  else if (Level2 != 0){
    Serial.print("Level 2 =  "); Serial.print(Level2); Serial.print("   ");
    sendSMS();
  }
  else if (Level3 != 0){
    Serial.print("Level 3 =  "); Serial.print(Level3); Serial.println("   ");
    sendSMS();
  }  
  delay(1);//delay ms


//void setup() {
//  loop();
//}

void sendSMS() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!GSMTEST.init()) {
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("INIT ERROR\r\n");
  }  
  Serial.println("GSM INIT SUCCESS");
  Serial.println("START TO SEND MESSAGE ...");
  Serial.print("..");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(".....");
  delay(1000);

  GSMTEST.sendSMS(PHONE_NUMBER,MESSAGE); //DEFINE PHONE NUMBER AND TEXT

}

void readSMS(){
     //READ THE INCOMING SMS MESSAGE
   Serial.println("   ");
   Serial.println("   ");
   messageIndex = GSMTEST.isSMSunread();
   if (messageIndex > 0) { //AT LEAST, THERE IS ONE UNREAD SMS
      GSMTEST.readSMS(messageIndex, message, MESSAGE_LENGTH, phone, datetime);           
      //IN ORDER NOT TO FUL SIM Memory, IS BETTER TO DELETE IT
      GSMTEST.deleteSMS(messageIndex);
      Serial.print("FROM NUMBER: ");
      Serial.println(phone);  
      Serial.print("DATE/TIME");
      Serial.println(datetime);        
      Serial.print("RECEIVED MESSAGE: ");
      Serial.println(message); 
   }  
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with my code? :(

Comment: it is incomplete again and you didn't post the error messages. one of the libraries has a variable called `message` so don't use this name

Comment: That is all the code. 

The error message is sendsms is not declared in this scope.

Comment: You forgot to close your `loop()` function - so the `sendSMS()` function is inside it and never gets declared.

Comment: Where is that? :(

Comment: As @Majenko said, count the number of curly brackets after the "void loop() {" line.  You will find there is none which match w/the curly bracket in the "void loop () {" line of code. So you confused the compiler.  And now you are getting errors from the compiler which are confusing you.  (Fair's fair :)! )

Comment: Consider editing your original question instead of re-posting. You need to make more of an effort to make your questions clear. Add text to the question explaining the problem. And make the title specific to the problem And try to format the code by highlighting the code and picking "code" from the menu. Remember: The point of stack exchange sites is to create clear and concise questions & answers that other people can find and use over and over again.